# Pandas: Pivot with comma separated string aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

How might I use comma separated string aggregation here as a form of a pivot table?

Consider this small example:

```
# mwe
df = pd.DataFrame({'property': ['DriveProductRevision', 'DriveProductRevision', 'DriveProductId', 'ProductNumber'],
                   'value': ['CXV84M1Q', 'CXV84M1Z', 'Samsung', 0]})
```

My attempt:

```
df.pivot_table(columns='property', values='value', aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

The expected output:

```
DriveProductRevision    DriveProductId  ProductNumber
CXV84M1Q, CXV84M1Z         Samsung            0
```

Comment: `df.groupby([col1,col2])[col3].agg(','.join)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually to a `groupby` + `agg(list)` + `.str.join`:

```
df = df.assign(value=df['value'].astype(str)).groupby('property')['value'].agg(list).str.join(', ').to_frame().T.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  DriveProductId DriveProductRevision ProductNumber
0        Samsung   CXV84M1Q, CXV84M1Z             0
```

Comment: Apologies, the initial `df` code I pasted was incorrect.

Comment: @John check now :)

Comment: Wow, I have never seen `assign` -- thank you, learning something new!

Comment: Yeah, `assign` is pretty useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the lambda passed to `aggfunc`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(columns='property', values='value', 
                      aggfunc=lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else ', '.join(x))
       .rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
      DriveProductId DriveProductRevision ProductNumber
value        Samsung   CXV84M1Q, CXV84M1Z             0
```